# I need to return value of json expression

Tags: json, json-extract

My expression is

```
 {
    "author": "%{\"id\" => \"f63b6f8a-4e3e-4884-8ce8-21a7885da7a7\", \"name\" => \"Bye\", \"type\" => \"AUTOMATOR\"}"
  }
```

How do I return AUTOMATOR in the above express?

I am using `JSON_EXTRACT(author,"$.type")`. Tt is not returning anything

Answer (score 0):

Your json seems to be not valid.

Correct json will be:

```
 { "author": {"id" :"f63b6f8a-4e3e-4884-8ce8-21a7885da7a7", "name": "Bye", "type" : "AUTOMATOR"} }
```

you can validate JSONs online, for example at: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

Comment: How do I get the value of TYPE?

Comment: Can you please help me return the value of  "type" in the correct json that you have shared? what expression should I use?

Comment: SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('{ "author": {"id" :"f63b6f8a-4e3e-4884-8ce8-21a7885da7a7", "name": "Bye", "type" : "AUTOMATOR"} }', '$.author.type');

Comment: I have checked the JSON from https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#

JSON format seems to be correct. The solution that you have shared works on the expression shared by you but not with the original express.

Comment: the string {
    "author": "%{\"id\" => \"f63b6f8a-4e3e-4884-8ce8-21a7885da7a7\", \"name\" => \"Bye\", \"type\" => \"AUTOMATOR\"}"
  }  is json but value of author is a only string not a valid json

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to get the value of "TYPE" from the string?

Comment: with JSON instruments - no, you should write custom parser for it

Comment: Cool. I think you are right. Can we convert that string in json and then get the value of "type"?

Comment: replace "=>" with ":" then I think you can JSON_EXTRACT(this_new_string,'$.type')

Comment: I cannot replace => with : . I am parsing data in Google cloud. JSON_EXTRACT is giving me null..